# Why do I get the error "Unexpected token" for this.state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I'm trying to make a login form and learn React as well. I'm basing everything on React's official documentation. However when I try to do my stuff and add new user inputs, it doesn't compile.

The code returns an error saying Unexpected token (9:22):
(token spotted with arrows)

```
       7 |         super(props)
       8 |         this.state = {
    >  9 |             firstName = '',
         |                       ^
      10 |             middleName = '',
      11 |             firstName = '',
      12 |             middleName = '',
```

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Signup.css';

class Userform extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstName = '',
            middleName = '',
            firstName = '',
            middleName = '',
            lastName = '',
            birthdate = '',
            address = '',
            contactNumber = '',
            email = '',
            year = '',
            department = ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleInputChange(event) {
            const target = event.target;
            const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
            const name = target.name;

            this.setState({
                [name]: value
            });
        }
  
    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A new enty has been submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="user-form">
                <div className="main-wrapper">
                    <div className = 'signup-banner'>
                        <h1>Registration Form</h1>
                    </div>

                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                First Name:
                                <input type="text" name='firstName'  id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autoComplete="off" />
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Middle Name:
                                <input type="text" name='middleName'  id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Last Name:
                                <input type="text" name='lastName' id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off" />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Birthdate:
                                <input type="text"  name="birthDate" id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Address:
                                <input type="text" name='address'  id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Email:
                                <input type="text" name ='email' id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off" placeholder='firstname.lastname@domain.com'/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Contact Number:
                                <input type="number" name="contactNumber"  id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off"/>
                            </label>
                        </div> 
                            
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Year:
                                <input type="text" name="year"  id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <label>
                                Department:
                                <input type="text" name="department" id="user-input" onChange={this.handleInputChange} autocomplete="off"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="info-wrapper">
                            <input type="checkbox" id='agree-box' onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            <p>Agree to Terms and Conditions</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
      
export default Userform;
```

I am really new to React and I have no one to ask right now. The login form is expected to be submitted in a MySQL db using node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            middleName: '',
            firstName: '',
            middleName: '',
            lastName: '',
            birthdate: '',
            address: '',
            contactNumber: '',
            email: '',
            year: '',
            department: ''
            };
```

your state is an object should be written as such

Comment: amazing, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo on declaration object. The correct way is

```
this.state = { firstName: "" }
```

Comment: appreciated , thank you.